# Заменить все строчные буквы на заглавные и наоборот, но только на кириллице Си

Tags: c, строки, кириллица

С латиницей всё довольно просто:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello, WoRlldoQQ!!";

    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
            s[i] -= 'a' - 'A';
        else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
            s[i] += 'a' - 'A';
    }

    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

А вот Русские символы кодируются 2 байтами в UTF-8 и я не знаю как это можно реализовать, помогите)

Comment: [icu4c](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4c/) - если вам нужно нормальное решение для всех языков. Если вы хотите что-то наколеночное, можно соорудить программку, которая будет хранить внутри или загружать снаружи таблицу перекодировки для верхнего/нижнего регистров. Своебразная упрощённая реализация [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) .

Comment: Вот [таблица](https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF) unicode cyrillc (обратите внимание, что от `А` до `а` ровно 32 (т.е. `1 << 5`) байта, а вот описание [кодирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) unicode в utf-8. Сами попробовать не хотите? (по ходу можете задавать уже конкретные вопросы)

Comment: @avp, если исходный код сам в UTF8, таблица не нужна. Достаточно по одной строке на букву. Можно их даже в общую строку собрать разбив пробелами - `"а б в г д ..."`. Можно и не разбивать, но тогда будет нужно немного кода. По таблице делать замену последовательностей байтов. Хорошая учебная задача.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, это же жутко неэффективно. Я не зря обратил внимание на константную разницу. Тут надо просто внимательно посмотреть и может придется пару сравнений сделать прежде чем заменить несколько бит. (не далее как сегодня обсуждали на работе тему, почему нынешние программисты не могут без гигабайт и гигагерц ...)

Comment: @avp, я говорил только о форме задания данных. Их можно переработать в регулярное выражение (я говорю о конечном автомате), в trie, в hash-таблицу, в lookup-таблицу. Производительность будет не хуже чем у ICU.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, я еще раз говорю, никакая дополнительная память в этой задаче не нужна. В общей задаче, поддерживающей все языки -- нужна. А тут нет

Comment: Всем спасибо, вы мне подали хорошую идею - использовать широкие строки, по крайней мере это не сильно повлияет на память. Или вы видите какие-то недостатки в моём плане?

Comment: Нормальное решение. Немного не бьётся с вопросом, который говорит что входная строка должна быть в UTF-8. Но вы автор вопроса, вам виднее, что в вопросе важно, что нет.

Comment: Все консольные приложения работают в CP866. И при вводе и выводе строк, всё в ASCII (0-255). Если у вас источник строк в иной кодировке, то нужно конвертировать для вывода в CP866, а для введенных данных конвертировать обратно :) Поэтому если источники данных, и файлы для хранения могут быть в ASCII то тому и быть :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, как можно сделать оставаясь в [UTF-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024)
(признаюсь, парой сравнений дело не ограничилось, но как и обещал в комментариях, совершенно без перекодировочных таблиц в памяти и без преобразований в unicode (т.е. wide chars)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// 5 high bits of first utf-8 byte is key to the size of utf-8 symbol
// 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1
// 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 // 16 ascii
// 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 1 // 8  cont
// 2 2 2 2  3 3 4 1 // 1 -- err

#define UTF8_LTAG (0x3a55ULL << 48)

#define UTF8_LEN(C) ({                          \
      int _x = ((C) >> 3) & 0x1f;               \
      int _l = (UTF8_LTAG >> (_x << 1)) & 3;    \
      _l + 1; })

void
change_utf8_rus_case (unsigned char *s)
{
  if (s[0] == 0xd0) {
    if ((s[1] > 0x8f && s[1] < 0xa0) || s[1] > 0xaf)
      s[1] ^= 0x20;
    else if ((s[1] > 0x9f && s[1] < 0xb0))
      s[0] ^= 1, s[1] ^= 0x20;
    else if (s[1] == 0x81)  // Ё
      s[0] = 0xd1, s[1] = 0x91;
  } else if (s[0] == 0xd1) {
    if (s[1] >= 0x80 && s[1] < 0x90)
      s[0] ^= 1, s[1] ^= 0x20;
    else if (s[1] == 0x91)
      s[0] = 0xd0, s[1] = 0x81;  // Ё
  }
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char str[1024] = "ПриВет МиР; ёЁ; HelLO WORld!!!";

  puts(str);

  int step;
  for (int i = 0; str[i]; i += step) {
    step = UTF8_LEN(str[i]);
    if (step == 1 && isalpha(str[i]))
      str[i] ^= 0x20;
    else if (step == 2)
      change_utf8_rus_case((unsigned char *)(str + i));
  }

  puts(str);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ g++ -O2 utfrus.cpp && ./a.out
ПриВет МиР; ёЁ; HelLO WORld!!!
пРИвЕТ мИр; Ёё; hELlo worLD!!!
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Еще одна реализация функции для изменения регистра русских букв использует перевод символа из кодировки utf-8 в 32-бит Unicode, но так же не использует никаких структур в памяти
(обе реализации функций смены регистра можно вызывать только для 2-х байтных символов utf-8).

```
void
chng_case_rus_utf (unsigned char *s)
{
  uint32_t v = (s[0] & 0x1f) << 6;
  v |= (s[1] & 0x3f);

  if (v > 0x40f && v < 0x450) {
    if (v < 0x430)
      v += 32;
    else
      v -= 32;
    s[0] = 0xc0 | ((v >> 6) & 0x1f);
    s[1] = 0x80 | (v & 0x3f);
  } else if (v == 0x401) // Ё
    s[0] = 0xd1, s[1] = 0x91;
  else if (v == 0x451) // ё
    s[0] = 0xd0, s[1] = 0x81;

}
```

Обе реализации имеют примерно одинаковый размер на ассемблере (от 80 до 128 байт, первенство зависит от оптимизации (с `-Os` chng_case_rus_utf немного больше, а с `-O2` чуть меньше)) и выполняются за примерно одинаковое время (chng_case_rus_utf чуть медленнее).

---

Что не понятно, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге использовал широкие строки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    wchar_t s[] = L"ПриВет МиР; HelLO WORld!!!";

    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        wchar_t c = s[i];

        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            s[i] -= 'a' - 'A';

        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            s[i] += 'a' - 'A';

        else if (c >= L'а' && c <= L'я')
            s[i] -= L'а' - L'А';
            
        else if (c >= L'А' && c <= L'Я')
            s[i] += L'а' - L'А';
    }

    printf("%S\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Буковки `ё` и `Ё` проверьте